# How to get all the function names where the global variables are used?

Tags: c++, clang, libtooling

I am working on libtooling with clang. I have developed a tools to find the global variables and where those global variables are referred.

Now, i want to get the function name which uses those Global variables.

Here is the Sample Code

```
int Var;

int display()
{
  Var = 10;
return Var;
}

int main()
{
  display();
return 0;
}
```

Here, i want to get that global variable `Var` is referred in Function `display`.

How can i get this Output using LibTooling clang? Please Let me know if there is any solution.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do with `libTooling`. If you already found `DeclRefExpr` nodes that refer to global variables, you can walk up the AST to their `FunctionDecl` parents.

On the other hand, walking up the AST requires Clang to construct a mapping from nodes to their parent nodes (which might be pretty expensive for big translation units). Here I've put together a short solution that just finds function referring to global variables and prints their names:

```cpp
class GlobalVariableFinder final
    : public RecursiveASTVisitor<GlobalVariableFinder> {
public:
  static bool find(FunctionDecl *CandidateFunction) {
    GlobalVariableFinder ActualFinder;
    ActualFinder.TraverseDecl(CandidateFunction);
    return ActualFinder.Found;
  }

  bool VisitDeclRefExpr(DeclRefExpr *SymbolUse) {
    // we are interested only in variables
    if (auto *Declaration = dyn_cast<VarDecl>(SymbolUse->getDecl())) {
      Found = Declaration->hasGlobalStorage();
      // if we found one global variable use, there is no need in traversing
      // this function any further
      if (Found) return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
private:
  bool Found = false;
};

class VisitingASTConsumer final
    : public ASTConsumer,
      public RecursiveASTVisitor<VisitingASTConsumer> {
public:
  void HandleTranslationUnit(ASTContext &C) {
    this->TraverseTranslationUnitDecl(Context->getTranslationUnitDecl());
  }

  bool VisitFunctionDecl(FunctionDecl *CandidateFunction) {
    if (GlobalVariableFinder::find(CandidateFunction)) {
      llvm::errs() << CandidateFunction->getQualifiedNameAsString() << "\n";
    }
    return true;
  }
};
```

If you want to store global variable references, you might want to modify the `GlobalVariableFinder` class to include additional logic.

Following solution produces the following output on this snippet of code:

```cpp
int Var;

int display()
{
  Var = 10;
  return Var;
}

int foo() {
  return Var;
}

int bar() {
  return foo();
}

int main()
{
  display();
  return 0;
}
```

```
display
foo
```

You can notice that it includes only functions that syntactically use global variables. If you want the algorithm to find `bar` as well, you'll need to build a call graph of the target program and propagate the information about global variables by the reversed edges of the graph (i.e. from `foo` to `bar` in our example).

I hope this information is helpful. Happy hacking with Clang!